# WooCommerce Pinpoint Booking system not showing prices correctly

Tags: plugins, woocommerce, calendar, cart, checkout

I'm Pinpoint booking system for reservations and WooCommerce for payment. And I see the following problem:

The system is supposed to calculate prices based on number of selected days for the booking, but, when selecting multiple days for a booking site, in the WooCommerce cart the amount reflected in the woocommerce screen is not what is reflected in the booking pinpoint piece (the booking Pinpoint piece is calculating correclty the amount based on qty of days, but the WooCommerce section shows the price for only 1 item).

For example, if I book for 2 nights at $8/night, the check in/check out part of the cart shows $16, but the Woocommerce part of the cart page shows QTY 1 at $8 (being the product price for a single product).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your question is off topic on StackOverFlow as it's not directly related to programming. This is just about settings… You need to respect all this following steps: https://pinpoint.world/wordpress/documentation/woocommerce/

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec but I followed that instructions and it didn't work. I used the forum for this topic as I found another user who did the same and I supposed it was correct. Sorry if that's not the point. But people helped him and the link configuration is not working for me.